# Decode MCE (Machine Check Exception) in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, freeze

I have a system running Ubuntu 18.04, which is randomly freezing. In the boot log entries like

```
mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4: e600000000020408
```

appear. In older Ubuntu versions, `mcelog` could be used to decode these entries. `mcelog` has since been removed. How do I decode the log entries to figure out where the fault comes from in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Something like "Bank 4" usually means a bad RAM stick in bank 4. You should run memtest to check.

Answer (score 0):

`mcelog` can still be compiled and executed manually. If you have git and a build toolchain installed, you can run:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/cpu/mce/mcelog.git
cd mcelog
make
./mcelog --ascii < /path/to/logfile
```

The logfile should contain content similar to:

```
CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4: e600000000020408
TSC 0 ADDR fef13b80 
PROCESSOR 0:506c9 TIME 1565455642 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 38
```

`mcelog` will print decoded information to stdout.

Comment: Don't hesitate to provide a better solution in a new answer though ;)

Answer (score 0):

"The logfile should contain content similar to:
CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4"

In that case, you don't need mclog